# Multiple read from an InputStream at different rates

Tags: java, caching, stream, inputstream, outputstream

I'm about to load an online content (say an audio file). If I just open a connection to the remote file (for example by use of `new URL().openStream()`) and pass the remote `InputStream` to the audio player, it reads ***gradually*** from the network. If audio player library do not ask `InputStream` for more data, it reads nothing from the network, and then when the library claims more, it reads again.

My problem is that I want to start caching the next online audio file, as soon as the loading process of the first one is finished. Using a normal `InputStream`, reading is complete as the audio playing is done, which is not good since I want it read faster if network bandwidth allows, so that caching the next audio file. My audio files are smaller that 3mb so can be safely cached to the memory. I only prefetch a single file, so no problem with memory leak.

Is there any type of caching `InputStream`, which also allows concurrent read? I can then run a thread and cache the audio faster than the audio player consumes the data.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you create a second thread to perform the downloading. Download files as quickly as possible in this thread and push the data over to your main playback thread.

Comment: Well, this is what I have in mind, but I should write my own ConcurrentInputStream impl. I asked if there is already an implementation out there.

Comment: commons-io has a DemuxInputStream but I'm not sure if it's helpful.